# How to Convert a String into Integer Array in C#

Tags: c#, linq, xor

I am new to C#. I am trying to solve a problem in which I have to find uncoupled integers. I am using an online compiler.

Given the input

`1, 2, 3, 1, 2`

The program should output:

`3`

I created the following program -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
class Solution {
    static void Main(String[] args) {
        int[] num;
        int accum=0;
        int j=0;
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        input = input.Replace(",","");
        
            
        num = input.Select(int.Parse).ToArray(); 
             

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++)
           accum ^= num[i];
           Console.WriteLine(accum);

    
    }
}
```

I am having trouble in converting string `1, 2, 3, 1, 2` into integer array.

I am having following errors

```
 error CS1061: Type `string' does not contain a definition for `Select' and no extension method `Select' of type `string' could be found. Are you missing `System.Reactive.Linq' or `System.Linq' using directive?
/usr/lib/mono/4.7.2-api/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
Solution.cs(18,29): error CS1061: Type `int[]' does not contain a definition for `length' and no extension method `length' of type `int[]' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
/usr/lib/mono/4.7.2-api/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
```

When I added `System.linq`, it gave me

`` error CS0234: The type or namespace name `linq' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing an assembly reference? ``

Comment: To start it is Linq with the uppercase L. Then before Select, Split the input string in its parts and then Select with Parse (And remove the Replace of comma)

Comment: @Anonymous if u resolve the issue, don't forget to accept my answer :)

Comment: @SachithWickramaarachchi sure, I will try all the solutions today :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] num;
    int accum = 0;
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    num = Array.ConvertAll(input.Split(','), int.Parse);

    for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
        accum ^= num[i];
    Console.WriteLine(accum);

}
```

Or by using Linq, just replace as follows, and you should need to use `System.Linq` namespace.

```
num = input.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

.NetFiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/bahpg9

Answer (score 1):

[Select method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0) is applicable for enumerable types and not `string` type. You need to convert the string input to an array of strings, before trying to convert each element to `int`.

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string[] inputs = input.Split(',')
int[] num = inputs.Select(x => int.Parse(x.Trim())).ToArray();
```

Comment: String *is* enumerable, as a list of chars - but the OP doesn't want that

Answer (score 0):

The following provides an extension method to check if all values entered can be an int and if so create an int array.

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hL7X7r) and [class project](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/ConverterLibrary) with similar code for double, floats etc.

There is a lot more code than prior replies granted yet the code presented here is not just for one operation, place into a class project which can then be used by other projects.

```
public static class NumericArray
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Determine if each element in the string array can represent an int
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool AllInt(this string[] sender) =>
        sender.SelectMany(item => item.ToCharArray()).All(char.IsNumber);

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a string array to an int array
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">string array which can represent integers</param>
    /// <returns>int array</returns>
    public static int[] ToIntegerArray(this string[] sender)
    {

        var intArray = Array
            .ConvertAll(sender,
                (input) => new
                {
                    IsInteger = int.TryParse(input, out var integerValue),
                    Value = integerValue
                })
            .Where(result => result.IsInteger)
            .Select(result => result.Value)
            .ToArray();

        return intArray;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return a string array without spaces in elements
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="separator">deliminator</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string[] Strings(this string sender, char separator = ',') 
        => sender.RemoveAllWhiteSpace().Split(separator);

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove all whitespace from a string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string RemoveAllWhiteSpace(this string sender)
        => sender
            .ToCharArray().Where(character => !char.IsWhiteSpace(character))
            .Select(c => c.ToString()).Aggregate((value1, value2) => value1 + value2);
}
```

Sample use where the input in this case is mocked.

```
namespace ConsoleNetCoreApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*
             * This would be string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
             */
            string userInput = "1, 2, 3, 1, 2";
            var result = userInput.Strings();
            if (result.AllInt())
            {
                var intArray = result.ToIntegerArray();
                foreach (var intItem in intArray)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{intItem}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("One or more values can not represent an int");
            }
        }
    }
}
```